# Find word in string c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, char

I have a string that contains something like this "'asd asd asd / * ... asd ' asd..."
I just want to retrieve only the value that starts from ' and ends the same character '. So from that string the value will be "asd asd asd / * ... asd"

I tried with the code below but it doesn't work.

```
string HDtext = new string(TextChar.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsSymbol(c))
                                   .TakeWhile(c => Char.IsLetter(c) ||
                                                   c == '*' ||
                                                   c == '/' ||
                                                   c == ' ')
                                   .ToArray());
```

Does anybody know how to retrive it correctly ?

Comment: [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I would use Regex here

```
string input = "'asd asd asd / * ... asd ' asd...";
var output = Regex.Match(input, @"'(.+?)'").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.Split` would be a option

```
string input = "'asd asd asd / * ... asd ' asd...";
string result = input.Split('\'')[1];
```

Comment: What if input doesn't have a `'` character. One solution: `input.Split('\'').Skip(1).FirstOfDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the index of the first and last occurrence of your desired char and then just take the substring between them. Like this, for example:

```
var __text = "'asd asd asd / * ... asd' asd...";
var __startIndex = __text.IndexOf("'") + 1;
var __length = __text.LastIndexOf("'") - __startIndex;

var __subString = __text.Substring(__startIndex, __length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LINQ:

```
string result = new string(str.SkipWhile(c => c != '\'')
                              .Skip(1)
                              .TakeWhile(c => c != '\'').ToArray());
```

If there are more than 2 `'` chars and you want to get everything between the first and the last:

```
string result = new string(str.SkipWhile(c => c != '\'').Skip(1)
                              .Reverse()
                              .SkipWhile(c => c != '\'').Skip(1)
                              .Reverse()
                              .ToArray());
```